# Ruby: Incrementing number of type string

Tags: ruby

I am working with an API that requires me to pass in numbers as strings. I need to increment the counter on each call.

I am using the following code:

```
days = days.to_i
days += 1
days = days.to_s
```

This works, but seems kind of sloppy. Is there a more way to do this in Ruby?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is. You can do:

```
days = days.next
```

or

```
days = days.succ
```

Or, you can use the bang (!) methods:

```
days.next!
```

or

```
days.succ!
```